# Scroll nas Row bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, eu estou com problemas que minhas row está saindo da area padrão e criando um tamanho para fora. [image: Aqui esta a imagem]

E meu HTML está assim:

```
section class="quemsomos">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="square1"></div>
            <div class="square2"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4 class="t-quemsomos"><span class="q">Q</span>UEM SOMOS</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="p-quemsomos text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic aspernatur eius enim, officia illo nemo doloremque, accusamus, harum minima labore odit necessitatibus blanditiis. Hic, nihil. Temporibus dicta tempore molestiae voluptatem.</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-about">SAIBA MAIS</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Cara se vc conseguiu com a ajuda de alguma resposta considere marca-la como aceita, assim ela não fica pendente se resposta aceita mesmo já tendo sido resolvida

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo é que você está fazendo a implementação da **GRID do bootstrap** incorretamente, por isto está sendo criado o `scroll` no **eixo x**. O sistema de **GRID do Bootstrap** usa uma série de contêineres, linhas e colunas para layout e alinhamento do conteúdo.

Resumo de como funciona a **GRID do bootstrap**:

> - O `.container` fornece um meio de centralizar e horizontalmente preencher o conteúdo do seu site. Use `.container` para uma largura de pixel responsiva ou `.container-fluid` para todos os tamanhos de dispositivo e porta de visualização.
> - A `.row`(linhas) são invólucros para `.col`(colunas). Cada `.col` tem um padding horizontal (chamada de medianiz) para controlar o espaço entre elas. Isso é então neutralizado na .`row` com margens negativas. Dessa forma, todo o conteúdo das `.col` são alinhados visualmente no lado esquerdo.
> - Em um layout de grade, o conteúdo deve ser colocado dentro de `.col` e somente `.col` podem ser filhos imediatos de `.row`.

**Figura Ilustrativa**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo sabendo-se disto, em seu código falta adicionar o `.container` ou `.container-fluid`, e corrigir diversas `.col`, onde você inseriu uma dentro da outra, então para corrigir isto faça o seguinte:

```
<section class="quemsomos">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="square1"></div>
                    <div class="square2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h4 class="t-quemsomos"><span class="q">Q</span>UEM SOMOS</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p class="p-quemsomos text-justify">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic
                                    aspernatur eius enim, officia illo nemo doloremque, accusamus, harum minima labore odit
                                    necessitatibus blanditiis. Hic, nihil. Temporibus dicta tempore molestiae voluptatem.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-about">SAIBA MAIS</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Nota**

> Sugiro que leia mais sobre a [GRID do boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) para entender melhor, pois seu código está estruturado errado e como você não informou com detalhes o que está tentando fazer, não posso te ajudar com isto.